# Showing an entire line of data from a factor within a column

Tags: r

I have data in the following format:

```
ID  Species Sex
1   spA     M
2   spB     F
3   spA     Sex Required
```

I would like to write a line of code that gives me the whole line of all rows that contain "Sex Required" in the Sex column

I have tried:

```
df[df$Sex == "Sex Required",]
```

But it is not working correctly. I know this is probably simple but I am new to R.

Comment: `df[df$Sex == "Sex Required",]` should work perfectly fine, unless there are additional spaces like @akrun mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 df<- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("spA", 
 "spB"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("F", 
 "M", " Sex Required"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Species", 
 "Sex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I assume that there are some spaces i.e. "Sex Required ", or " Sex Required"

```
df[df$Sex == "Sex Required",]
#[1] ID      Species Sex    
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)


df[grep("Sex Required", df$Sex),]
#       ID Species           Sex
# 3  3     spA  Sex Required
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
df$Sex <- str_trim(df$Sex)
df[df$Sex == "Sex Required",]
#  ID Species          Sex
#3  3     spA Sex Required
```